# What workflow should I use for parallel feature development? Each feature must be merged into master on its own

Tags: git, gitlab, git-workflow

I am wondering which would be the best approach in this case:

I have a `baseFeature` branch derived from master, and multiple feature branches derived from baseFeature. `baseFeature` has initial changes common to all the new feature branches.

My flow right now is to merge each feature branch back into `baseFeature` and then merge request `baseFeature` to upstream master. But this results in multiple features being combined in the same merge request to master (e.g. 10 features in one merge request). I want each feature to appear in master's history as a separate merge commits.

When I try to do separate merge requests from each feature branch, I get

> Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>   hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref

One solution is to use -f. But it says I am not allowed to force push.

I could have each feature be a branch off master and include in each the commits on baseFeature before starting any work. After finishing I would push the branch to master.

Which would be the best approach? are there any possibilities? All I need is to have different merge requests from each feature. But I cannot merge the baseFeature into master since is not reviewed yet.

Comment: Welcome Gaby V! Few questions: Is it not possible in your case to merge baseFeature into master first? Do all of the the "small" feature branches have to be worked on in parallel? Or do you plan to work on them sequentially?

Comment: @I.Raleigh: I cannot merge baseFeature first. We have to work in parallel with every feature. It's the first time I'm not working sequentially with merges and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: One thought I had was that you don't need to merge the "smaller" feature branches back into the baseFeature before merging them into master. So each "smaller" feature branch would have its own merge request. Its just the first merge request would carry all the history of the baseFeature as well. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @GabyV you need to clarify your question, because you state " I cannot push to master from the other branches except from baseFeature" yet in a comment below you imply that you are allowed to. I rolled back my change to the title because I am now not sure what the rules actually are. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61740113/2

Comment: @Inigo: So by "I cannot push to master..." I mean that I wasn't able because I got errors. I am allowed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that your question has been clarified, I'll update my answer.

> Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref

It means that you are pushing new commits to a branch that has diverged from yours -- i.e. has commits that you don't have. It prevents you from this for your protection.  Think about it: Both you and someone else (or maybe you in another context) made changes to the upstream branch. You can't just **push the state** of your local branch (because that is what push does) and overwrite upstream (well you can, with a "force push" `git push -f`, but DO NOT do that unless you actually want to overwrite upstream).

You haven't specified which branch you are pushing that results in this error. Local master to upstream master? Local feature branch to remote feature branch?

Regardless, since you are using *merge requests*, you shouldn't be pushing to master anyway.

Based on what I can tell of your workflow, this is what I think you should be doing:

1. Sync up your local master with upstream master.[1]
2. Then get any commits on master not in your feature branch into your feature branch. **I strongly recommend that you do this by rebasing** your feature branch.[2]
3. Retest your code. Fix as necessary.
4. Submit merge request.

If you don't know about rebasing, there are tons of articles on the web or StackOverflow. `git rebase` is one of the most important commands you should know.

---

[1] Your local master should always look just like upstream. You shouldn't commit changes to it directly. Given your merge-request-based workflow, changes should always flow as follows (simplified):

- feature branch --> upstream master (via merge request)
- upstream master --> local master (e.g. via `git pull`)

[2] You should do steps 1 and 2 regularly if there are changes being made to master. Otherwise you may be doing work on the feature branch that won't work with the latest changes on master.

Comment: This is exactly how I want to merge them. Every branch directly into master. But I thought it's not possible since I got "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally...". And It doesn't work with forcing too

Comment: Ok, I've edited your question further to clarify, and also updated my answer to solve your problem :)

Comment: I think understand now. To clarify, by upstrem you mean the remote repository. From my experience when the upstream was changed, I was still able to push my work. This is what I did with baseFeature I pushed it to upstream and then I would pull and rebase the remote commits and push them again. But why I am not allowed to do the same thing with branches derived from baseFeature?

Comment: Yes, upstream being the remote. You **cannot**  push changes from a local branch that has diverged from a remote. That is a fact. You may be confusing `push` with `merge request`. Or some other confusion. Or you may be doing something else. There is a lot of detail you are leaving out when you talk about what you've been doing, so I can't say. Anyway, I've clarified my answer a little more. Sorry I've spent a ton of time on this and can't anymore. Part of the problem is that I and others have to guess what you are actually doing exactly.

Comment: Also the first thing you should always do is understand the error message you are getting. You may need to better understand the command you are executing that results in the error. You can also simply search the web with the text of the error. Yours comes up a lot for a lot of people and there are even many SO questions about it.

Comment: The answer was on point. So you 'guessed' right. I followed your steps and it's working. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a visual representation of what you could do to maintain your two requirements:**

1. Every feature branch should be checked out from the base feature
2. Every feature branch should have its own merge request to master

```
_master___________________________________________________
            \                                  /  /    /
             \___baseFeature__                /  /    /
                              \              /  /    /
                               \_featureA___/  /    /
                                \             /    /
                                 \_featureB__/    /
                                  \              /
                                   \_featureC___/
```

**Explanation**

Here you have your two branches to start: `master` and `baseFeature`. It appears that from your description, that `baseFeature` has some commit history that you would like to include in all of the feature branches. So logically, you idea to check out each of the feature branches from there makes sense `git checkout -b featureA origin/baseFeature`.

Now there is nothing requiring you to merge these branches back into `baseFeature` as they also have the correct commit history for master. Therefore, they are eligible to merge into master directly.

First caveat: whichever feature branch gets merged in first, `featureA` in the visual example, will bring with it `baseFeature`.

Second caveat: if the different feature branches are working on the same files, then merge conflicts will have to be resolved.

Comment: Yes, This is the best option. This is what I was trying to do but I was not able to do so. "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally" was the first error. I tried to force the push but I wasn't allowed. So this would be the perfect scenario but I'm not even sure it's possible.

Comment: @GabyV The error usually indicates you have to pull from the branch you are trying to push to before pushing.